# Using range, len, and % to print string

Tags: python

I'm a newbie to Python and one of our practice examples is in the code below but there is no feedback on what the code is doing. The question in the exercise asks "How many times is P printed out" I've provided the output below.

From what I understand on my own, the length of s is 6 and the range is 0 to 5 but since we are saying "range(len(s))" are we basically asking the loop to run 6 times?

Also, can someone help me understand the print(s[idx % 2])? How does the print statement generate the output shown below? If I were to change it to print(s[ 0:2 ] then I would be given "pypypy" horizontally which is different.

Thank you for the help.

```
s = "python"
for idx in range(len(s)):
   print(s[idx % 2])
```

Output

```
p
y
p
y
p
y
```

Comment: Yes, range(6) gives you [0,1,2,3,4,5] - 6 numbers. `idx` will take each of those values in turn during the loop. The `%` operator is modulus. so `idx % 2` will alternate between 0 and 1 as `idx` changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings in Python are arrays of bytes representing unicode characters. However, Python does not have a character data type, a single character is simply a string with a length of 1. Square brackets can be used to access elements of the string. Therefore you can get the character at position 1 (remember that the first character has the position 0) via the following code snippet, e.g:

```
a = "Hello, World!"
print(a[1]) // e
print(a[2]) // l
```

---

Now looking at why your code outputs what it does (second part of your question). Recall that `%` is the [modulo operator](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/modulus.html).

In the first run, idx = 0. So your statement becomes:

```
   print(s[0 % 2]) = print(s[0]) = 'p' -> first letter of s.
```

Next idx = 1. So your statement becomes:

```
   print(s[1 % 2]) = print(s[1]) = 'y' -> second letter of s.
```

Next idx = 2. So your statement becomes:

```
   print(s[2 % 2]) = print(s[0]) = 'p' -> first letter of s.
```

And so on, 6 times (idx takes values of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5).

---

P.S. Commenting on your comment regarding setting `print(s[ 0:2 ])` - this is known as [string slicing](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/strings#string-slices) (essentially call out a range of characters from the string) - [0:2] means you are starting at index 0 and extend up to but not including index 2, so 'py'.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed breakdown. This helps a lot!

Answer (score 2):

> are we basically asking the loop to run 6 times?

Yes

> can someone help me understand the print(s[idx % 2])?

Yes

> How does the print statement generate the output shown below?

The `%` operator is the modulo operator. It gives the remainder of a division. For the range in question, the results are

0 divided by 2 is 0 with a remainder of 0

1 divided by 2 is 0 with a remainder of 1

2 divided by 2 is 1 with a remainder of 0

3 divided by 2 is 1 with a remainder of 1

4 divided by 2 is 2 with a remainder of 0

5 divided by 2 is 2 with a remainder of 1

As you can see, the remainder toggles between 0 and 1.

Indexing the string will thus result in `s[0]` which is `p` and `s[1]` which is `y`.

Comment: This is a great and detailed explanation.  Thank you very much Thomas. Now I see exactly what's going each time the for loop is being ran.